# Setting opacity info in ArcGis Api for Javascript overwrites featureLayer.renderer.colorInfo

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I'm having trouble setting the color of a feature layer in ArcGIS api for javascript. I have a feature layer, which, on the load event I set its renderer's colorInfo and opacityInfo. Both work individually, but when I try to set a specific color, and set the opacity of the color together, the color reverts to a default color from the feature layer. I've searched the documentation and tried everything--not a lot of examples pertinent to simple stuff like this. It's like colorInfo and opacityInfo conflict with each other.

```
<script>
require(["stuff"],function(stuff){

map = new Map("div",center, zoom, etc);

var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("url",{
    id: "id",
    infoTemplate: esri.InfoTemplate({title: "${title}",content:     "${content}"}),
    outFields:["*"],
    visible: true
));

featureLayer.on("load", function(){
featureLayer.renderer.setColorInfo({field: 'my_field', colors: ['#mycolor']});
featureLayer.renderer.setOpacityInfo({opacityValues: [0.25]}); //removes mycolor and sets it to some weird default color
});

});
```

All I'm really trying to do is define a specific color and set its opacity. I've also tried using a SimpleRenderer, but this seems to conflict with a toggle menu I'm using, so trying to stick with the feature layers own renderer methods.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be working as it should.

https://jsfiddle.net/kmqqxfuq/

Please make sure there are no other events being fired which set the feature color/opacity. (feature layer on opacity-change etc)